# Getting no data for sending a POST request with JSONArray using volley

Tags: android, arrays, android-volley

I'm trying to send a data using POST method and get a JSONArray array but i'm getting no data from the server, when i test my php file with specific value then it's ok but when I use POST method for send the key then not giving any data.

here is my JSONArray Request:

```
final JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, jsonURL, (String) null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    int count = 0;
                    while (count < response.length()){
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(count);
                            DataProvider dataProvider = new DataProvider(jsonObject.getString("Name"),
                                    jsonObject.getString("Url"),

                            arrayList.add(dataProvider);
                            count++;

                        } catch (JSONException e) {

                            Toast.makeText(context,"Error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    CarFragment.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }
    ){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {

            Map<String,String> param = new HashMap<String,String>();
            param.put("id","01675904620");
            return param;
        }
    };
    Singletone.getSingletone(context).addToRequest(jsonArrayRequest);
```

and here is my php code:

```
<?php

$user_id = $_POST["id"];

$db_name = "andr";
$user_name = "user";
$password = "12345";
$server = "localhost";

$con = mysqli_connect($server,$user_name,$password,$db_name);


$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = ".$user_id.";") or die("Error: " . mysqli_error($con));

$response = array();

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    array_push($response, array("Name"=>$row["name"],"Url"=>$row["image_url"]));
}

echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: `return super.getParams();` seriosuly?

Comment: Selvin that was by mistake of post. I tried that when not getting data. thanks for your correction. but do you know where is my actual wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is how you send data to server using volley

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("ID","1234");
            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Above you can see that once you post id to server ,the server will send its response to your app , and it will be available here `String response`.
you can further process this response and fetch whatever you want.

```
JSONObject jsonObject=null;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);//json is the response you get from server
        users = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);//JSON_ARRAY is the name of your array

        ids = new String[users.length()];


        for(int i=0;i<users.length();i++){
            JSONObject jo = users.getJSONObject(i);
            ids[i] = jo.getString("ID");

        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

For more refrences:

https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-tutorial-to-get-json-from-server/ 
https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-volley-post-request-tutorial/

Thanks....Happie Coding

Comment: thank you bro, I really appreciate you. is there no way to pass data from jsonArrayRequest?

Comment: i didnt get you

Comment: have you seen my code, there i did JsonArrayRequest  instead of StringRequest. so I asked you that, can't I send the value of id from JsonArrayRequest.

Comment: no, your actual response from the server is available her "String response"